# images in real android 4.0 device are not looking same as in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i am developing an application for android 4.0. that app in  emulator is looking in good size but when we check that application in real device, all images in apps are being very small in size. what should i do? please help me.

Comment: could you post several screenshots and related codes?

Comment: all image are of good size in emulator, but in real device it is being very small in size. so how to give screen shots of real device?

Comment: i am posting screen shot of both emulator as well as of real device.

Comment: DDMS can take the screenshot :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I am following you correctly you are under the illusion that the emulator will mimic a device exactly? And that because your design looks good on the emulator it will translate exactly over to the device?

If that assumption is correct then you need to be aware that the emulator is never going to give you that kind of accuracy. From my own experience the emulator will help as a guide but it cannot and should not really be used as a like for like match against a set or specific device. This all comes down to the fact that different phone manufacturers use different chipsets and render their screens differently to each other. The best thing you can do is to effectively follow the guidelines here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html to provide a layout that closely resembles what you want.